# How to set all External Domain Links with nofollow Attribute from Header Footer Content and Excerpt using PHP?

Tags: php, themes, links

I am trying to set all external links with nofollow attribute on all Wordpress site. I found so many site where code is available only for content and excerpt. But i want to set nofollow attribute on all external domain links from header, footer, content everywhere.

Please Provide Reference or PHP Code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. Please edit your question and let us know what you have tried so far and/or how the links are printed in header and footer. If they are hard coded, you need to manually edit the template files and add the nofollow attribute. If they are being added dynamically, like from database, there might be a way, but not in all cases.

Comment: All external links from website required with nofollow attribute except internal, for instance in Header Social Links, Content External Link, Sidebar External Links, Footer External links etc.  The question asked is correct

Comment: So, how they are being added? Show us a sample code from `header.php`.

Comment: Not in Specific section as you saying about header.php code this will implement in function.php. For instance if i apply the following code in js all external link changed with nofollow attribute. 

`var hrefToCheck = "domain.com" // change this string

noFollowExternalLinks(hrefToCheck); // call to run the function below

function noFollowExternalLinks(siteHref) {

  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
    if (!link.href.includes(siteHref)) {
      link.setAttribute("rel", "nofollow");
    }
  })

}`

How this is possible through php code.

Comment: See, implementing this using JavaScript is easy, but won't serve the purpose if you want to do it for optimization. Crawlers will be done by the time the attribute added. There's no one shot way to implement this using PHP/HTML. The process will be different for each section of your site.